# Proper way to get information from a large number of DB's

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Our company has many MS SQL databases (more than 130). My goal is to obtain some simple data from each of them (actually it's just an int value). This task needs to work every 5 minutes. So far, I have the following code:

```
values = {}

    for server in serversList:
        serverName = server.server_name
        database = server.db_name
        user = 'user'
        password = 'password'

        try:
            conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+serverName+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+user+';PWD='+ password)       
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute('SELECT value FROM table')
            value = cursor.fetchval()
            values['serverName'] = value
            conn.close()
```

Total processing time is around to 2.5-3 minutes.

How can I optimize this? I've tried to make it async, but MS SQL doesn't support asynchronous work. Maybe I need to use multithreading? I've heard it's not so good to use multithreading in Python.

Comment: Look at multiprocessing - https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process. The idea is to access multiple DB's at the same time

Comment: MS SQL doesn't need to support async for you do it in Python. The DBMS won't know if the call it gets comes from a synchronous or an ansynchronous process.